# Unable to use CefSharp in winforms for AnyCPU. Same is working when change build to x64 bit

Tags: c#, cefsharp

We have a C# application in which we are using CefSharp.Core.dll, CefSharp.dll and CefSharp.Winforms.dll and application build was x64 and everything was working fine for 64-bit systems. But now one of our clients requested application to run on 32-bit Systems. I have tried everything but all in vain. Installed CefSharp (57.0) from nuget C++ redistributable is also installed as I have mentioned that application is working fine if I change project build to x64. Don't know what I'm missing. Also tried these solutions "https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714".
[image]

Comment: Your 32bit application is attempting to load a 64bit dll. Please edit your question and add more detail.  Have a read over https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/#golden-rule if you need some pointers

Comment: How do you know that my application is attempting to load a 64-bit dll? I have added references from x86 folder located in Packages folder.
"C:\TFS\POC\packages\CefSharp.Common.57.0.0\CefSharp\x86\CefSharp.dll" and "C:\TFS\POC\packages\CefSharp.Common.57.0.0\CefSharp\x86\CefSharp.Core.dll" It was working for the reference "C:\TFS\POC\packages\CefSharp.Common.57.0.0\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.dll" and "C:\TFS\POC\packages\CefSharp.Common.57.0.0\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.Core.dll"

Comment: And what's unclear ? There is not coding error. I just wanted some information what can be the possible reasons in the explained situation. Might be someone already faced it and have some information about it.

Comment: The `BadImageFormatException` quite clearly shows you are attempting to load a `64bit` version of `CefSharp.Core.dll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i got the solution. Posting it as a solution so that it can help others in future. The mistake was i had multiple projects in a solution and I was changing only project's build to (32-bit i.e x86) but was not changing solution's platform build and deploy. Right Click Solution->Properties->configuration-> and Changed build to x86 worked for me.[image]